# Lambda syntax to remove rows from List

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

Given:

```
string removeRows = "";
int i = 0;
foreach (var row in userStats)
{
    if (row.OrderRow.RegistrationType == "Want Removed")
    {
        removeRows = removeRows + i.ToString() + ",";
    }
    i++;
}
```

what's the Lambda syntax to execute the removal?

Comment: The question isn't clear, but assuming you want to remove items from a `List<T>`, you could try `userStats.RemoveAll(row => row.OrderRow.RegistrationType == "Want Removed");`

Comment: @Ani, you should have posted that as an answer.

Comment: Not sure the best way to handle this - i posted the original question because i needed to work around the 'cannot change a member of the being looped'. If I had looked more carefully for that particular problem I would have found several relevent threads - what looks like string abuse if my attempt to shorten my original code. Should probably get out of that habit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand, you code collects the indexes of rows to be removed and forms a string with them comma-separated. It doesn't actually removes these items so I don't know why you're doing it.

If `userStats` is `List<T>` where `T` is your row type, you can use `RemoveAll` method that actually removes all items that match given condition:

```
userStats.RemoveAll (r => r.OrderRow.RegistrationType == "Want Removed");
```

I think your code abuses strings, you both use them for collecting indexes and for registration type. I wonder if `RegistrationType` could be an enumeration instead:

```
enum RegitrationType {
    ShouldBeRemoved,
    // add other types here
}

userStats.RemoveAll (r =>
    r.OrderRow.RegistrationType == RegitrationType.ShouldBeRemoved);
```

Comment: Right on the spot about the string abuse. String is not code, don't use it as if it were.